# change math color except in titles in beamer

Tags: beamer, color, titles

I have used `\setbeamercolor{math text}{fg=blue}` to turn all my text in mathmode in blue. However I have also math in titles (and subtitles) and I would prefer the formulas to have the same color as the titles instead of blue.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Do you need both inline math and display math in blue color?

Comment: Yes, I need inline and display math in blue color. But not in the titles...

Thanks for the welcom.

Answer (score 5):

`beamer` has a command `\donotcoloroutermaths` to remove math coloring.  You can insert this into the template for titles as in the example below.  I use `red` as the maths color for better clarity in the demonstration.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{math text}{fg=red} 

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\donotcoloroutermaths}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{A title with $x=y$ maths}
  Text and maths \( y=z \).
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```