# Change math color except in block titles in beamer

Tags: beamer, color, block

I have used `\setbeamercolor{math text}{fg=blue}` to turn all my text in math mode in blue. However I have also math in block titles and I would prefer the formulas to have the same color as the block titles instead of blue.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\setbeamercolor{math text}{fg=blue}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{block}{A title with math text $f(x)=y$}
     Block body with math text $f(x)=y$.
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

I want it looks like this:

[image]

I found a [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304759/53954) that modifies math text color in frame titles using `\donotcoloroutermaths` by setting `\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\donotcoloroutermaths}`. But simplify changing the `frametitle` to `blocktitle` causes errors.

Comment: Please add a [short, but compilable test file](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a `document` environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could redefine the `block begin` template like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\setbeamercolor{math text}{fg=blue}

\setbeamertemplate{block begin}{%
  \par\vskip\medskipamount%
  \begin{beamerboxesrounded}[upper=block title,lower=block body,shadow=true]%
    {\raggedright\usebeamerfont*{block title}\donotcoloroutermaths\insertblocktitle}%
    \raggedright%
    \usebeamerfont{block body}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{block}{A title with math text $f(x)=y$}
     Block body with math text $f(x)=y$.
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have written a tutorial that allows you to customize all the content in the beamer presentation at the link below, you can download it in the description. https://youtu.be/JJzW59-0pZ0?si=b8_GRtDR7_33h1kU